# MongoDB ObjectID type on front-end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, requirejs, amd, objectid

I am having trouble finding information online as how to use Mongo ObjectID instances on the front-end.

I can't answer these questions:

(1) is it safe to serialize/deserialize ObjectID objects to/from JSON?

(2) How can I require the ObjectID module with AMD/RequireJS on the front-end?

(3) Is it better to just use strings on the front-end and just convert strings to ObjectIDs on the backend?

So yes I am having trouble working with and manipulating ObjectID objects on the frontend because I don't have the ObjectID module on the frontend, or at least this is a perceived problem. I haven't seen any examples of how to do this nor have I seen much talk of it online at all. Perhaps I am not approaching the problem correctly.

Comment: Most of the time, your MongoDB driver, or your JSON library will convert the ObjectID to a string for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **No.**  Your JSON parser will likely fail, as JSON only stores certain datatypes, and `ObjectID` isn't one of them...

   Although, note that if you're stringifying your data it is possible that your MongoDB driver would in fact back this by returning a string from the ObjectID...  Here is an example in NodeJS:

   ```
   var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID,
       myObject = {test:ObjectID("55153a8014829a865bbf700d")};

   console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
   // {"test":"55153a8014829a865bbf700d"}
   ```
2. **No.** I'm not sure there are any modules out there yet that give the ability to use ObjectID's in browser JS.  [Although perhaps you can port this NodeJS to browser JS compatibility?](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/a905d41152eee34787efd0f01d8a2cdb63272587/lib/bson/objectid.js#L28-L50)
3. **Yes.** For now, I would say yes.  You can just use the string on the front-end; although, like I said ealier, if you can port the ObjectID peice to be browser compliant (which shouldn't be too hard), I don't think there would be any issues there.